# Compile error while archiving ios app with GPUImage

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, archive, gpuimage

Help! I got this error while archiving my ios app using GPUImage made by Brad Larson in github.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file libGPUImage.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file libGPUImage.a (3 slices)
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageBrightnessFilter", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ProcessViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageContrastFilter", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ProcessViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImagePicture", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ProcessViewController.o
```

My app ran fine when I run it with device or simulator but when I tried to archive it, this error popped out. **How do I resolve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my chat with rajesh, the answer to my question is that I need to change my architectures in build settings to **Standard architectures (no arm64)** which is previously the one including 64-bit

Comment: also import is (im combination with setting to build standard architectures only) to set TRUE to "Build active Architectures only"  for Release Builds.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your library for ios device

[image]

before adding it to your project in-order to Archive it.

Comment: The way I added it to my project is first I ran the build.sh in GPUImage folder, then I just copied the generated bin and lib folder to my project. Then my project ran fine when I use my ipad to test it. Just when I wanted to archive it, the errors popped out

Comment: I got your point completely. Have you added you library in root folder or reference alone?

Comment: is your library built for IOS device?

Comment: I just built it for my iPad successfully. But when I disconnected the iPad and built it for ios device, it failed with the same errors. I don't get it. Is my iPad not ios device?

Comment: Is the same issue occurs When you disconnect the device? You are checking your project but I m asking you to build your **library** for device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48535/discussion-between-oscar-yuandinata-and-rajesh)